# 14.04 increasing backlight above a certain level does not work

Tags: 14.04, ati, backlight

I've read every topic I came across but couldn't find a problem similar to mine.

I have a laptop with ati graphics card and have fglrx installed. my function keys for increasing - decreasing brightness work but to max level is still too low.

when looking into files like max_brightness and actual_brightness I see that its at "9"

anyway, after following some instructions I added acpi_backlight=vendor to my GRUB and now I can increase brightness further with FN keys but after a certain level it does not affect the screen.

looking into max_brightness and actual_brightness from the now available "acer-wmi" displays 15 but actual brightness is visually stuck at the same level as before. (one plus thing is that I can now decrease the backlight finer but that was not my main goal here...)

any help?

btw, adding 20-intel.conf file to xorg.conf did not have a pleasant effect (I could no longer login and brightness levels seemed unchanged.

also; suggested xrandr and xbacklight solutions seem to have no effect whatsoever.